# How to submit a post request using Java?

Tags: java, http-post

Here is   a [test webpage](http://chyngyz.com/test.php) that has a form with `method="post"`

I need to enter the values and print the resulting page to `the console`. Here is    my full code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Post {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://chyngyz.com/test.php");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
        params.put("fname", "Peter");
        params.put("lname", "Pen");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));
    }
}
```

It executes but prints the original page. It looks like the  parameters are not submitted .  How can I improve my code ?

---

Here is my `test.php`

```
<form method="post" action="testResult.php">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

Here is my `testResult.php`

```
<?php
$fname= $_POST['fname']; 
$lname= $_POST['fname'];
?>
<p> Your name is 
<?php
print $fname . ' ' . $lname;
?> </p>
```

Comment: I entered the `fname` and `lname` in the website it is not even going to another page

Comment: Thank you. Did you enter this url: `http://chyngyz.com/test.php?fname=Peter&lname=Pen` . It is not supposed to work, because this is not `get` method

Comment: I just double checked it. If you enter manually `Peter` and `Pen` and click `Submit` it does go to another page

Comment: there you go, wrong php file in url

Comment: Thank you. I will change test to testResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
URL url = new URL("http://chyngyz.com/test.php");
```

by:

```
URL url = new URL("http://chyngyz.com/testResult.php");
```